# UPDATE não funciona com dados de um POST

Tags: php, mysql, html5, mysqli, sql-update

Estou obtendo os dados de um POST e tentando atualizar uma tabela mysql, porém o UPDATE não funciona de forma alguma.

Se eu utilizar da forma descrita abaixo, apenas substitui os valores por vazio.

```
<?php
 require('../configs/conect_apostas.php');

$id=$_SESSION['id']; 
$selectOption = $_POST['selectOption'];

$dadosAlterar = $_POST['dadosAlterar']; 

$sql2 = "UPDATE dados SET alunos = '$dadosAlterar' WHERE 1";
if ($mysqli->query($sql2) === TRUE) { 
  echo "Sucesso!";
}

?>
```

Se eu der um `echo $dadosAlterar` recebo corretamente o valor.

Se eu utilizar o código abaixo, o UPDATE é realizado com sucesso.

```
<?php
 require('../configs/conect_apostas.php');

$id=$_SESSION['id']; 
$selectOption = $_POST['selectOption'];

$dadosAlterar = "Mateus"; 

$sql2 = "UPDATE dados SET alunos = '$dadosAlterar' WHERE 1";
if ($mysqli->query($sql2) === TRUE) { 
  echo "Sucesso!";
}
?>
```

Se eu realizar um INSERT funciona corretamente com o POST, porém preciso realizar um UPDATE.

Comment: Consegue postar o erro gerado no update?
Se você tentar Rodar essa query direto no banco ela funciona substituindo as variáveis por valores reais?

Comment: Felipe, não tem erro, apenas substitui por vazio. A query da sucesso, substituindo o que tiver por vazio. E sim, já tentei rodar a query diretamente e funciona.

Comment: INSERT INTO dados (alunos) values ('$dadosAlterar')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
alunos = '$dadosAlterar'


tenta usando esse método, pois facilita a checagem se tu esta inserindo um novo registro ou alterando um já existente

Comment: Você já imprimiu `$sql2` antes de executar para ver o que está sendo montado?

Comment: bfavaretto, acabei de imprimir, e por incrível que parece a variável  ´´´$dadosAlterar´´´ está correta. 
echo do $sql2 -> UPDATE dados SET alunos = 'Mateus' WHERE 1
Recebendo o dado corretamente do POST.

Comment: Felipe Fernandes, tentei com o ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, mas mesmo assim está substituindo por vazio.

Answer (score 0):

Galera, consegui uma solução. Adicionei uma verificação e está funcionando.

```
<?php
 require('../configs/conect_apostas.php');

$id=$_SESSION['id']; 
$selectOption = $_POST['selectOption'];

$dadosAlterar = trim($_POST["dadosAlterar"]);

if($dadosAlterar){ 
  $sql2 = "UPDATE dados SET $selectOption = '$dadosAlterar' WHERE id = '$id'";

  if ($mysqli->query($sql2) === TRUE) {   
    echo "Sucesso!";  
  }      
}
?>
```

meu código final ficou assim. Obrigado a todos!